# Jq get the first main values programatically

Tags: json, bash, jq

Im trying to get the first 2 names in the following example json, without having to call them

test.json

```
{
  "BI_Arch": [{
    "Read": ["RDS", "Redshift", "Athena"],
    "Write": ["Quicksight"]
  }],
  "Data_Engineers": [{
    "Write": [ "S3", "Glue","Lambda", "Athena", "EMR", "Databricks", "RDS" , "Redshift", "Kinesis", "SQS", "SES", "SNS", "AWS SFTP"],
    "Read": ["KMS", "Secret_Manager"]
  }]
}
```

what i want to get is `BI_Arch Data_Engineers` without having to resort in naming them, something like the opposite response of `jq .[] test.json` that writes down only those names, is there a way to get it?

this is the `jq .[] test.json` for making it simpler

```
[
  {
    "Read": [
      "RDS",
      "Redshift",
      "Athena"
    ],
    "Write": [
      "Quicksight"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "Write": [
      "S3",
      "Glue",
      "Lambda",
      "Athena",
      "EMR",
      "Databricks",
      "RDS",
      "Redshift",
      "Kinesis",
      "SQS",
      "SES",
      "SNS",
      "AWS SFTP"
    ],
    "Read": [
      "KMS",
      "Secret_Manager"
    ]
  }
]
```

It prints everything but the names, i want the names without everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keys` function as in:

```
jq keys test.json
[
  "BI_Arch",
  "Data_Engineers"
]
```

possibly obtaining "raw" output with:

```
jq -r keys[] test.json
BI_Arch
Data_Engineers
```

Comment: If you literally want the first two keys, use `keys_unsorted[:2]`, the main point being that `keys` sorts the key names.

Answer (score 4):

Pipe the object through the `keys` filter, and slice it if you really want the first 2 of more-than-2:

```
% jq 'keys[:2]' tmp.json
[
  "BI_Arch",
  "Data_Engineers"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `jq '[keys]'`

Here's an online tool
https://jqplay.org/s/csowtIQRaZ